# adding tomcat to startup on a debian lenny box

Tags: debian, tomcat

How can I add a service (like tomcat) to my startup routine so it starts up upon server restarts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `update-rc.d` command. It is used in debian to install and remove startup services such as tomcat and others. The startup script needs to exist in `/etc/init.d/` first for it to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a line in /etc/rc.local that simply calls tomcat's startup command. It will be executed at boot.